# opennebula VM submission failure

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, scp

I am new to OpenNebula, the cloud is up and running but the VM is failed to be submitted to a node. I got the following error from the log file.

ERROR: Command "scp ubuntu:/opt/nebula/images/ttylinux.img

node01:/var/lib/one/8/images/disk.0" failed.

ERROR: Host key verification failed.

Error excuting image transfer script: Host key verification failed.

The key verification keeps failing. I need to know what is going wrong ... thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you ssh as oneadmin between the computers and accept them as a known host.

Make sure that you ssh as the same hostname that the onevm command is using (i.e. if it's connecting to host `name1` you can't ssh to `name1.domain.com`, or you can but then edit the known hosts file to correct this).